# Data Viewer in VS Code using Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, data-science, dataview

Whenever I am using Jupyter Notebooks and I want to inspect my dataframes, I go to the variable tab and when I open the dataframe it always splits the screen separating the tab from my Notebook and from the dataframe. I really dont know how to open the dataframe without it splitting the screen, it used to not do this at the begining but now it happens alwasys.

I already searched for setting with regards to tabs, Jupyter variables, data viewer but seem not to find anything